# What is a good way to get file size in bytes using Fortran?

Tags: function, file, fortran, intel-fortran

Is there a way to get the filesize in Fortran using Intel Fortran?

I was using `stat` which works great in gfortran, but it is not available in ifort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
INQUIRE(FILE=filename, SIZE=file_size)
```

`filename` is a character scalar, `file_size` is an integer scalar that will be defined with the size of the file in file storage units ("in bytes" on ifort), or -1 if the size cannot be determined.