# Find input file size in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, progress-bar, fortran90, filesize

I'm trying to create a progress indicator based on the total file size vs. file size read so far. I am working with a binary file.

```
open(unit=unitvector, file=vectorname, status='old',form='unformatted')
do while (ios.eq.0)
    read(unitvector,end=888,err=888, iostat=ios) KX, KY, KZ, KNAME, NV, NE, WEIGHT
    nkcount=nkcount+1
    call progress(FILE SIZE, PROGRESS SIZE)
    allocate( Vector(3,NV) )
    read(unitvector) (Vector(1,I),Vector(2,I),Vector(3,I),I=1,NV)
.
.
.
 end do
```

To compile i use:

```
ifort -warn all -traceback -free util.F fold2Bloch.f90 -o fold2Bloch
```

So every iteration of the loop I would call the subroutine `progress` and send the total file size and the size read so far. How can you find out the total size and size read so far? Or is there a better way to approach this progress indicator idea?

Comment: So i figured out how to find the total size, which can be done by: inquire(unit=unitvector, size=tot_len)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good way to get file size in bytes using Fortran (ifort)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711835/what-is-a-good-way-to-get-file-size-in-bytes-using-fortran-ifort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the size (in bytes) of a file use the following:

```
inquire(unitvector, size=tot_len)
```

However, I still have no idea how to figure out what byte the pointer is at after a read() instruction.

Comment: You marked the answer as accepted that means, you don't need anything more in this subject. You can open a new question, if you have another problem.

Comment: The problem is you are working with a sequential file, which is record oriented, not byte-oriented. Stream access file would be easier.