# Syntax error in INQUIRE(inpunit,flen=iflen) in gfortran but not in Lahey

Tags: file-io, fortran, gfortran, filesize

I try to compile my code using gfortran. I got this error:

```
   **INQUIRE(inpunit,flen=iflen)
                  1
   Error: Syntax error in INQUIRE statement at (1)**
```

This code was compiled before with lahey. With a quick research I find that parameters of INQUIRE have different meaning in gfortran compared to lahey.

1. inpunit is a scalar INTEGER expression that evaluates to the
   input/output unit number of an external file.
2. flen is a scalar default INTEGER variable having the length of the file in bytes.

My question is when using gfortran is this statement correct to get the same functionality as in Lahey:

```
   **INQUIRE(inpunit,RECL=iflen) **
```

Are these two statements similar?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, these two are completely different.

`flen=` is a nonstandard extension specific to the Leahy compiler and returns the length of the file.

`recl=` is the maximum record length in the file (if the file is connected - opened, otherwise it is 0) https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-inquire-recl-specifier

To be standard conforming you should use `size=`. Be aware that the result will be in file storage units. Gfortran uses bytes, but other compilers may use 4-byte words.
See [What is a good way to get file size in bytes using Fortran (ifort)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711835/what-is-a-good-way-to-get-file-size-in-bytes-using-fortran-ifort) [Find input file size in fortran90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497529/find-input-file-size-in-fortran90)