# I want to read text of unknown lenght from a file into a vector like character(len=1) a(3000) using Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I want to read text of unknown lenght from a file into a vector like character(len=1) a(3000) but the input file does not have an "end of file marker"

I tried things like:

```
     open(2,file=surnames.txt,status='old')
     read(2,15, IOSTAT=ios,END=20,ERR=20)(a(i),i=1,3000)

      isize=0
      do while (ios == 0)
        isize=isize+1
        read(2,15, iostat=ios, end=20) a(isize)
      end do

15    format(a1)
20    continue
```

but nothing works

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Please say what *nothing works* mean. It does not say anything useful. Does it crash? Is there any error message? Are the results wrong? How wrong? Please [edit] your question with more info.

Comment: You should probably use the `stream` access.

Comment: I want to convert the input file to a vector of characters in such a way of being able to deal with each character of the file individually. By "nothing works" I meant he final vector a(i) is not correct. Thanks !

Comment: The answer of IanH on [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/385790) site is very helpful in this case.

Comment: Or just make a(LEN=3000) and then you get the whole length of the line however long it is... LEN_TRIM(a) then tells you how long that line was...

Comment: You could use INQUIRE to find out the file size before reading.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711835/what-is-a-good-way-to-get-file-size-in-bytes-using-fortran